# Finding matches where GROUP BY COUNT(*) is 1

Tags: mysql, join

Say I have tables

**organisation**:

```
id | name
---------
1    ACME
3    MGM
```

**org_type**:

```
type_id | org_id
----------------
1         1
2         1
2         3
```

How do I query a list of org names where there type is 2, and no other type is linked with that organisation? In other words, a query that returns only organisation with `org_id` of 3 from above data.

I'm trying queries like

```
SELECT o.name
FROM organisation o
JOIN org_type ot ON o.id=ot.org_id
WHERE ot.type_id = 2
GROUP BY ot.org_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

But obviously that just returns the list of ALL orgs where a link to type_id 2 exists. I only want those where no other link exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should help you out.

It works with an delivered table named `org_type` what filters out double `org_id`.

That delivered table will be matched with where filter `org_type.type_id = 2` to make sure that type_id = 2

```
SELECT 
   org_type.type_id
 , org_type.org_id
 , organisation.name
FROM (
 SELECT 
     type_id
   , org_id
 FROM 
   org_type
 GROUP BY
   org_id
 HAVING 
   COUNT(*) = 1
) AS 
  org_type
INNER JOIN 
  organisation
ON
  org_type.org_id = organisation.id
WHERE 
  org_type.type_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kludgy:

```
SELECT o.name
    FROM organisation o
    JOIN org_type ot ON o.id=ot.org_id
    GROUP BY ot.org_id
    HAVING  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ot.type_id) = '2';
```

Comment: Or without the DISTINCT if `type_id` is unique per `org_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether it meets your requirement:

```
select * from org
where not exists ( select 1 from org_type
where org_type.type_id <> 2
and   org_type.org_id = org.id
)
and exists ( select 1 from org_type
where org_type.type_id = 2
and   org_type.org_id = org.id
)
```